# gmail script (stats report) deployment

Tags: deployment, gmail, installation

I need to develop a simple gmail script that collects some stats. I've found an example, something like: go to GoogleDocs, create a new spreadsheet, go to Tools -> Script Editor, enter your script.  That's fine and clear. But how to deploy it to my customers and how they can run it?

Is it possible to give them a link or a package from which they can simply install this script and a new button "Stats" will appear in their gmail account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only [Contextual Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets) or Sidebar gadgets in GMail app. You can't make a script or its result appear directly in GMail.

An apps script can be published to a gallery. See [Sharing Your Scripts section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_writing_scripts). It'll have to wait for a Google review though. I tried submitting a script awhile back but it never got a confirmation that it was published at some point.

A couple of fast ways:

- You send your customers the source code with instructions (e.g. "Go to Tools => Script Editor", "Paste my code", etc..)
- Share the spreadsheet along with the script itself (you'll need to enabled script code sharing even if the spreadsheet is shared already) and tell them to make a copy, including the script.